# Objective C decodeBoolForKey not compatible with BOOL

Tags: objective-c, pointers, boolean, nscoding

So I have an NSObject which implements NSCoding. In my decoder method it needs to retrieve a BOOL that belongs to the class among other properties.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setRandomObject:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"randomObjectKey"]];
        [self setMyBool:[decoder decodeBoolForKey:@"myBoolKey"]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This however throws the following warning on the line with `[self setMyBool ...` (Yellow warning, still runnable).

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to parameter of type 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *')
```

I don't understand why it is trying to send a pointer of a bool to a bool. If anyone knows how this can be fixed please let me know! Thanks a ton.

---

Also, it's very late right now, and me being exhausted, I may have just missed something simple so please bear with me.

Comment: Is `myBool` a property? What's the type signature of `setMyBool:`?

Comment: Read that error message again -- you're converting *from* integer (that's the BOOL) *to* a pointer to BOOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your method look like this?

```
- (void)setMyBool:(BOOL *)value
or:
@property BOOL *myBool;
```

Because it should be:

```
- (void)setMyBool:(BOOL)value
or:
@property BOOL myBool;
```

Comment: Either that, or the property declaration uses the wrong type.

Comment: Well I just discovered that I accidentally declared the property with type `BOOL *` instead of `BOOL`. Your answer did help though because after reading it I double checked the property declaration and noticed the mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So it appears I accidentally declared the property as a `BOOL *` instead of a `BOOL`. I changed it and everything works now. After reading the comments and answers I decided that the method was correct, then looked at the declaration of the property. Thank you very much, coding late at night is harder than I thought.